# How to use regular expressions in R to only get specific data?

Tags: r, regex

Hi lovely stackoverflow friends,

i recently came up with the following problem:

Having a huge datatable loaded into R i started to use `which()`to get the needed entries. But it turned out, that the data structure in some entries, is not really redundant.

E.g. one part of the table called stimuli can contain the following:

```
money_01, money_02, money_3, ..., money_xy
```

but in fact the numbers do not care.

So when i try to get specific data of my table i usually do:

```
SpecificData <- DataTable[which(DataTable$Block == "1" & DataTable$Orientation == "approach" & DataTable$Stimuli == "money"), c(1,2,3)]
```

where `money`should count for all `money_xy` cases too. How can i do that?

Thank you! Regards, Chris.

**Edit 01:** (thanks for helping me out)
a more detailed example considering a table:

```
Subject, Block, Orientation, Stimuli
01,      7,     approach,    money_73
02,      2,     approach,    person_3
03,      3,     avoid,       neutral_93
04,      1,     approach,    money_11
```

And from this table i want to get all subjects, their block and orientation if their block = 1, orientation = approach, stimuli = money

where i do not know how to use "money" so that it matches all variants of money_xy from the table.

**Edit2: [SOLVED]**

Thanks to Imran Ali's answer (and all the other suggestions too) i solved the problem. As it turns out there is no need to use `which()` we can simply use `grepl(matching_string, source_string)` in my specific case this resulted in:

```
SpecificData <- DataTable[DataTable$Block == "1" & DataTable$Orientation == "approach" & grepl('money', DataTable$Stimuli), c(1,2,3)]
```

Thank you!

Comment: please provide example dataset and expected output, your description of the problem is quite unclear as of now.

Comment: You have multiple conditions inside of your `which`.  Do you want all of those to apply?  i.e. join them with & ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
x <- c("money_01", "money_02", "money_3", "someothervalues", "someothervalues2", "money_xy")

     title         y
1         money_01 1
2         money_02 2
3          money_3 3
4  someothervalues 4
5 someothervalues2 5
6         money_xy 6

testdata <- data.frame(title=x, y=seq(1:length(x)))  
result <- testdata[grepl('money', testdata$title),]  

   title   y
1 money_01 1
2 money_02 2
3  money_3 3
6 money_xy 6
```

Update:
Using your sample data, the following should work

```
result <- testdata[grepl('money', testdata$Stimuli) & testdata$Block==1 & testdata$Orientation=="approach", ]
```

Comment: The star in grep is a Kleene star and is not necessary here.

Comment: It should be grepl in the last chunk.